# IE returns empty/blank canvas with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to create a canvas from my website with the code below. That canvas I'm uploading to my server as a PDF with jsPdf. This works fine on all browsers except Internet Explorer (I tried it in IE 11). The canvas is created but is completely blank. I've included a Promise plugin.

Do I need to add something extra for IE to work or use different code?

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    background: '#FFFFFF',
    logging: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {      
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [screenWidth, screenHeight]);
        var marginLeft = 0;
        var marginRight = 0;            
        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"), "jpg", marginLeft, marginRight, screenWidth, screenHeight, null, 'FAST');   
        var finalPDF = btoa(pdf.output());
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data", finalPDF);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("post", "uploadPDF.php", true);
        xhr.send(data);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I fixed the blank canvas. The problem was with elements with `position:absolute;`. I switched them to `position:relative;` just before creating the `canvas` en switched them back in the `onrendered:` callback.

Comment: But where? First find out if html2can or jsPDf is the reason by adding the canvas to the page and see what is in it. `onrendered(function(can){document.body.appendChild(can);}` if you see a canvas as expected the fault not with html2Canvas continue such tests until you locate the point at which the canvas becomes blank, then you can work on finding a solution.

Comment: This happens on the last page of a series of pages, just found out on the second one the canvas is already blank/empty. On the first page it works great so that's strange. Going to check the differences between these pages now.

Answer (score 0):

After logging: true set one more property useCORS: true that should fix the problem